# first dash is not recognized as delimiter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A have a problem with url rewriting.
I have this url:

http://www.example.com/apps/1-health-directory

With this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^apps/([^_]*)-([^_]*)$ /app_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The problem is that when I want to get the id and name param, this is what is returned:

```
app_details.phpid=1-health&name=directory
```

And the correct it would be

```
app_details.phpid=1&name=health-directory
```

How can be done?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect. You're trying to match until first dash then use `[^-]` instead of `[^_]` (dash != underscore)

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^apps/([^-]*)-(.*)$ /app_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```